# ingress points to wrong port on a service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-service

I have a Kubernetes service that exposes two ports as follows

```
Name:              m-svc
Namespace:         m-ns
Labels:            
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=my-application
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.233.43.40
Port:              first  8080/TCP
TargetPort:        8080/TCP
Endpoints:         10.233.115.178:8080,10.233.122.166:8080
Port:              second  8888/TCP
TargetPort:        8888/TCP
Endpoints:         10.233.115.178:8888,10.233.122.166:8888
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

And here is the ingress definition:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: f5
    virtual-server.f5.com/http-port: "80"
    virtual-server.f5.com/ip: controller-default
    virtual-server.f5.com/round-robin: round-robin
  creationTimestamp: 2018-10-05T18:54:45Z
  generation: 2
  name: m-ingress
  namespace: m-ns
  resourceVersion: "39557812"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/m-ns
  uid: 20241db9-c8d0-11e8-9fac-0050568d4d4a
spec:

  rules:
  - host: www.myhost.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: m-svc
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /first/path
      - backend:
          serviceName: m-svc
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /second/path
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 172.31.74.89
```

But when I go to `www.myhost.com/first/path` I end up at the service that is listening on port `8888` of `m-svc`. What might be going on?

Another piece of information is that I am sharing a service between two ingresses that point to different ports on the same service, is this a problem? There is a different ingress port the port 8888 on this service which works fine

Also I am using an F5 controller

After a lot of time investigating this, it looks like the root cause is in the F5s, it looks like because the name of the backend (Kubernetes service) is the same,  it only creates one entry in the pool  and routes the requests to this backend and the one port that gets registered in the F5 policy. Is there a fix for this? A workaround is to create a unique service for each port but I dont want to make this change , is this possible at the F5 level?

Comment: Could you provide some steps to recreate the issue? I could check if this occurs in my lab environment.

Comment: Deploy an app with two exposed ports , create a single service with two exposed ports as in the question and then create a path ingress as in the question

Answer (score 4):

From what I see you don't have a `Selector` field in your service. Without it, it will not forward to any backend or pod. What makes you think that it's going to port `8888`? What's strange is that you have [`Endpoints`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors) in your service. Did you manually create them?

The service would have to be something like this:

```
Name:              m-svc
Namespace:         m-ns
Labels:            
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=my-application
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.233.43.40
Port:              first  8080/TCP
TargetPort:        8080/TCP
Endpoints:         10.233.115.178:8080,10.233.122.166:8080
Port:              second  8888/TCP
TargetPort:        8888/TCP
Endpoints:         10.233.115.178:8888,10.233.122.166:8888
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Then in your deployment definition:

```
selector:
  matchLabels:
    app: my-application
```

Or in a pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations: { ... }
  labels:                                
    app: my-application
```

You should also be able to describe your `Endpoints`:

```
$ kubectl describe endpoints m-svc
Name:         m-svc
Namespace:    default
Labels:       app=my-application
Annotations:  <none>
Subsets:
  Addresses:          x.x.x.x
  NotReadyAddresses:  <none>
  Ports:
    Name    Port  Protocol
    ----    ----  --------
    first   8080  TCP
    second  8081  TCP

Events:  <none>
```

Comment: Thanks, it exhibits the same result with selectors unfortunately and i did not manually set the endooints

Comment: I think it is pointing to port 8888 because when i hit the ingress host from the browser it shows me the service that’s listening on port 8888 and not 8080

Comment: Do I need a selector field in the ingress definition?

Comment: Not really, you don't. Btw, I tried this on my setup and it works for me with an nginx ingress controller.

Comment: Is your f5 load balancer a layer 4 or layer 7 load balancer?

Comment: I created a service for each port, this is an F5 limitation that it only creates an entry once for the service so the second port is compromised

Answer (score 0):

Your `Service` appears to be what is called a headless service: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services. This would explain why the `Endpoints` was created automatically.

Something is amiss because it should be impossible for your HTTP request to arrive at you pods without the `.spec.selector` populated.

I suggest deleting the `Service` you created and delete the `Endpoints` with the same name and then recreate the `Service` with `type=ClusterIP` and the `spec.selector` properly populated.

Comment: Hi Ive update the question to have a selector which doesnt seem to fix the problem, what do you mean by endpoints with the same name?